# Wrapping variadic tuple types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I wish to transform a tuple type `[T1, T1]` to some other `[T2, T2]`, where `T2` is a subtype of `T1`. So far this is my best attempt, but I could not figure out the return type on `variadicMapping`. My guess is that the solution involves the newly introduced variadic tuple types.

```js
type T1 = { property: string };
type T2 = T1 & { otherProperty: number };

const transformType = <T extends T1>(obj: T): T2 => ({
  ...obj,
  otherProperty: 0,
});

const variadicMapping = <T extends T1[]>(objects: T) => {
  return objects.map((e) => transformType(e));
};

const foo = [{property: 'propertyA' }, { property: 'propertyB' }] as [T1, T1];
const bar = variadicMapping(foo); // T2[] instead of [T2, T2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need variadic tuple types for this.  The problem is that the [TypeScript standard library definition for `Array.prototype.map()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d779a190535e52896cfe5100101173c00b6b8625/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1349) doesn't attempt to represent the fact that array length is preserved.  There is an open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#29841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29841),  asking for this to be addressed.

If you need the compiler to pay attention to length, you will need to use your own typing for `map()` via, say, [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces).  Possibly something like this:

```
interface Array<T> {
    map<U>(
        callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any
    ): { [K in keyof this]: U };
}
```

I'm using [mapped tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to represent the length preservation, and specifically [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) to capture the fact that we want to iterate over the keys of whatever *subtype* of `Array<T>` we happen to be using, such as a tuple.

But messing with definitions for such commonly-used methods might have unexpected results in other parts of your code base, so unless you'd like to worry about whether every use of `map()` should behave this way, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that the result of this specific call to `map()` is of a particular length and type:

```
const variadicMapping = <T extends T1[]>(objects: T) => {
    return objects.map((e) => transformType(e)) as { [K in keyof T]: T2 };
};
```

Either way you should get the behavior you want:

```
const bar = variadicMapping(foo); // [T2, T2]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.2#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)